# Show the current date every time a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, button, alert

I have the following code:

```
<html><body>
<script type="text/javascript"> function date1(){
    ????
    alert(<%=d%>);}</script>
<input type="button" value="date" onclick="date1()"/>
</body></html>
```

Instead of the ????, what will present the current date each time I'll push the button?

1. `<%String d = (new Date()).toString())%>`
2. `<%String d = "new Date()"%>`
3. `<%= Date d = new Date() %>;`

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Or a test?

Comment: Why not try? You know what you want to put there right? Are you having any issues?

Comment: If you need the date of the server, use ajax. If can be the date of the client, use javascript Date.

Comment: this is homework assignment . I  just dont understand the answer...

Comment: When you say you don't understand the answer, do you mean you've been told which option is correct but you don't understand why it is correct? Or that you can't figure out which is correct?

Comment: the answer i was given to, is 2. but i think who gave it to me, is wrong...

Comment: Since you've now had more time to think about this I'll say that I'm sure option 2 is the correct answer. Why do _you_ think 2 is wrong? If you can't clearly explain (to yourself - no need to tell me) why it is wrong, or why one of the other answers is right, then you don't really know. You need to look at each option in terms of what output will go to the browser and will that output (a) be valid JavaScript that can be run by the browser, and (b) actually achieve the desired result when it is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is homework I'll give you an explanation without explicitly stating which option is correct:

Remember that any server-side Java code will run only at the point when the JSP is requested/served, essentially producing text that will be output to the browser. The code in the line with the alert:

```
alert(<%=d%>);
```

Will output the contents of the server-side (Java) `d` variable between the parentheses of the `alert` statement. So the correct answer is whichever one will get a new JavaScript date each time the button is clicked, so you need to work out which one results in this output to the browser:

```
alert(new Date());
```

Only one of the answers does that.

Note: if you can't figure it out, try actually running the code with each answer and see which works. I think you'll find that one of the answers produces invalid JavaScript, one produces a server-side compilation error, and the other works.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what You are looking for?
You don't need JSP for such operation.

1.first option will produce compile error because Date cannot be resolved to a type (You need to use import statement on jsp) and 1 right bracket should be deleted. And if You fix that this option will produce static code as follow

```
alert(Thu Feb 09 22:20:08 CET 2012);
```

because JavaScript needs " to mark Strings this will produce "missing ) after argument list" and will not work.

2.second option is correct (just like [nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) said) because static code will looks like

```
alert(new Date());
```

And because Date is also JavaScript function this code will show alert window with date.

3.third option is totally messed up because <%= means "print" so "Date d =" is syntax error.

Comment: This is a question from my homework assignment.. I cant change tha code

Comment: then no. 1 is correct, second line will print "new Date()" and last is incorrect because of semicolon.

Comment: in the second answer - did you notice that it is alert(<%=d%>) and not alert(d)?

Comment: Yes, <%=d%> means print d variable, and d variable is setted by 1. Line

Comment: One of the options will produce the client-side code you show in your answer. That option is _not_ number 1.

Comment: is this a hint? :) can you plz explane yourself?